# in every coloring $1,...,n$ there are distinct integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $a+b+c=d$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

Prove that for every $k$ there is a finite integer $n = n(k)$ so that for any coloring of the integers $1, 2, . . . , n$ by $k$ colors there are distinct integers $a, b, c$ and $d$ of the same color satisfying $a + b + c = d$

Comment: This problem reminds me of the Generalized Shur Numbers. It is Theorem 8.27 in the book Ramsey Theory on the Integers by B. Landman and A. Robertson.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Ramsey's theorem we can choose $n=n(k)$ so that, for any coloring of the $2$-element subsets of an $n+1$-element set with $k$ colors, there is a $7$-element subset whose $2$-element subsets all have the same color.

Now suppose the numbers $1,2,\dots,n$ are colored with $k$ colors. Color the $2$-element subsets of the set $\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$ as follows: if $x,y\in\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $x\lt y$, give $\{x,y\}$ the same color as the number $y-x$. Thus there are numbers $x_1\lt x_2\lt x_3\lt x_4\lt x_5\lt x_6\lt x_7$ such that all the differences $x_j-x_i\ (1\le i\lt j\le7)$ have the same color.

Choose $i\in\{3,4\}$ so that $x_i-x_2\ne x_2-x_1$ and then choose $j\in\{5,6,7\}$ so that $x_j-x_i\ne x_2-x_1,\ x_i-x_2$.

Let $a=x_2-x_1,\ b=x_i-x_2,\ c=x_j-x_i$ and $d=x_j-x_1$. Then $a,\ b,\ c,\ d$ are distinct, and $a,\ b,\ c,\ a+b,\ b+c$, and $a+b+c=d$ all have the same color.

**Alternatively** choose $m=m(k)$ so that, for any coloring of the $2$-element subsets of an $m+1$-element set with $k$ colors, there is a $4$-element subset whose $2$-element subsets all have the same color, and let $n=n(k)=2^m-1$.

Now suppose the numbers $1,2,\dots,n$ are colored with $k$ colors. Color the $2$-element subsets of the set $\{0,1,\dots,m\}$ as follows: if $x,y\in\{0,1,\dots,m\}$ and $x\lt y$, give $\{x,y\}$ the same color as the number $2^y-2^x$. Thus there are numbers $x_1\lt x_2\lt x_3\lt x_4$ such that all the differences $2^{x_j}-2^{x_i}(1\le i\lt j\le4)$ have the same color.

Let $a=2^{x_2}-2^{x_1},\ b=2^{x_3}-2^{x_2},\ c=2^{x_4}-2^{x_3},\ d=2^{x_4}-2^{x_1}$. Then $a\lt b\lt c\lt d$ and $a,\ b,\ c,\ a+b,\ b+c$, and $a+b+c=d$ all have the same color.

This construction can be improved by using a [Sidon sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence) (also called a [Golomb ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler)) $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_m$ instead of $2^0,2^1,\dots,2^m.$

Comment: sorry can you explain that sign

Comment: so there are a,b,c,d such that a+b+c=d but how do i know that they are distinct

Comment: that's true but i don't understand how the seven helps