# Monochromatic Solution for $abc=d$

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Show that for every $k$, there exists a finite integer $n=n(k)$ such that for every coloring of {$1,2,...,n$} by $k$ colors, there are distinct $a,b,c,d$ of the same color satisfying $abc=d$.

I'm considering a method similar to the proof for Schur's Theorem, but I'm not sure how to proceed since we have $abc = d$.

Comment: I wonder if there's some way to use the fact that $x+y+z=w\implies2^x2^y2^z=2^w$?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599367/in-every-coloring-1-n-there-are-distinct-integers-a-b-c-d-such-that-ab?noredirect=1), esp @bof's solution.