# Prove that there exist three numbers of different colors such that $a+b=c$

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

We color the numbers from $1$ to $n$ ($n\ge 7$, I think) with three distinct colors, say white, black and red such that every color appears more than $n/4$ times. Prove that there exist three numbers of different colors such that $a+b=c$.

I started by assuming that there doesn't exist such integers then if we assume that the number $1$ is colored black that would mean that $$(C(i),C(i+1))\neq (W,R)\quad \forall i\ge 2$$
Where $C(k)$ is the color of the number $k$. Because otherwise we would have $C(i)=W$ and $C(i+1)=R$ Which contradicts our assumption . And that's where I got stuck

Comment: In any case, an argument similar to the following will work: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1599367/269764

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I didn't say that we can't have a string of black numbers. What I said is that if you choose any two consecutive numbers at least one of them is coloured black

Comment: You could have $C(i)=C(i+1)=W$ without contradicting your assumption.

Comment: @DanielMathias I really didn't think of that. But one thing I'm sure of is that two consecutive integers won't produce $W$ and $R$

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14384 may be relevant.

Comment: Also, Marc Budden, Schur numbers involving rainbow colorings, Ars Mathematica Contemporanea 18 (2020) 281-288, https://amc-journal.eu/index.php/amc/article/view/2019

Comment: Have you had a chance to follow those links, PNT?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No. And I don't really think the solution would require that much theory anyway.

Comment: So, you didn't even look at them? Not even to see whether, before getting into deep waters, they mentioned earlier, more elementary treatments of the question that interests you? Well, excuse me for trying to help you, I won't make that mistake again.

Comment: Who said I didn't look at them? @GerryMyerson

Comment: I asked whether you followed those links, and you answered, "No." If you didn't follow them, then it follows that you didn't look at them – you can't look at a webpage without following a link to it.

Comment: I thought that "following" means understanding those links. @GerryMyerson

Comment: OK, I'll give it another go. Theorem 5 of https://math.mit.edu/~fox/paper-FoxJungicRadoicic.pdf says, "For every $n\ge3$, every partition of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ into three color classes R, G, and B with $\min(|R|,|G|,|B|)>n/4$ contains a rainbow solution to the equation $x+y=z$. The term $n/4$ cannot be improved." The reference for the theorem is J Schonheim, On partitions of the positive integers with no $x,y,z$ belonging to distinct classes satisfying $x+y=z$, in R A Mollin, ed., Number Theory (Proceedings of the First Conference of the Canadian [continued]

Comment: [continued] Number Theory Association, Banff 1988), de Gruyter 1990, 515-528. There was earlier work of Esther and George Szekeres, mentioned in G Szekely, ed., (1995) Contests in Higher Mathematics, Miklos Schweitzer Competition 1962-1991, Problem Books in Mathematics, Springer. You know, you never know how much theory is going to be needed to solve a problem, until you've solved it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140571/discussion-between-pnt-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat.

Comment: I visited those links but they're talking about numbers $x,y,z$ from the same coloring?

Comment: If you want to be certain I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it, so I get notified. Anyway, Theorem 5, that I quoted, says "rainbow solution", which means solution from different coloring classes. The Schonheim title refers to $x,y,z$ from distinct classes. I bet the Szekeres reference is about different colors, as well. So, no, they are not talking about numbers from the same coloring.

Comment: I saw that Theorem 5 but I kept scrolling down to see the proof but they didn't provide it @GerryMyerson

Comment: The proof is in the Schonheim paper.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: Here's a very elementary paper. Section 2 is about $a+b=c$. https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/77/ajc_v77_p001.pdf

Comment: I don't really understand what they're talking about. They're kind of assuming the rainbow number already exists and they're just trying to optimize it, I think. @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Progress**

For convenience, let the colors be $A, B, C$. Assume WLOG that $1$ is colored with $A$, and let the color with the largest minimum integer colored with the respective color be $C$. Now, let $v$ be the minimum integer colored with $C$, note that $v \geqslant 3$ (since $A$ and $B$ must precede it at least once). Moreover, it is not possible to have $v = 3$ since you cannot color $1,2,3$ with $A,B,C$ respectively, because $1 + 2 = 3$. Thus, $v \geqslant 4$.

Now, for each positive integer $k$ with $1 \leqslant k < v$, note that $k + (v-k) = v$. Since $v$ is colored with $C$ and neither of $k$ or $v-k$ are colored with $C$, the colors of $k$ and $v-k$ must be the same. In specific, $v-1$ must be colored with $A$.

Now, what can the color of $v+1$ be? Since $1 + v = (v+1)$, the color of $v+1$ cannot be $B$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that the color of $v+1$ is $C$. Let $u$ be the minimum integer colored with $B$ (note that $1 < u < v$). We know that $v-u$ also has color $B$. By the minimality of $u$, we know that $u-1$ must have color $A$, and so must $v-u+1$. However, we now have $(v-u+1) + u = (v+1)$, and their respective colors are $A, B, C$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $v+1$ must be colored $A$.

Notice how the first $C$ is sandwiched between $A$'s? This is going to be the case in general. We prove this by induction. Our base case has already been established. Take any $C$ that occurs after the first one, say at position $w$ (where $1 < u < v < w$), and assume that the claim holds true for the previous $C$'s. We know that $w-1$ cannot be colored $B$, since $1 + (w-1) = w$. We also know that $w-1$ cannot be colored with $C$ since every previous $C$ is succeeded by $A$. Thus, $w-1$ is colored with $A$. Furthermore, assume $w+1 \leqslant n$ (else, there is no successor, so the $C$ at the end is... half-sandwiched?). We can again see that $w+1$ cannot be colored with $B$ since $1 + w = (w+1)$.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $w+1$ is colored with $C$. Recollect that $u$ is colored with $B$. Since $u + (w-u+1) = w+1$, we cannot color $w-u+1$ with $A$. As $(u-1) + (w-u+1) = w$, we cannot color $w-u+1$ with $B$. This implies that $w-u+1$ is colored with $C$. The induction hypothesis implies that $w-u$ is colored with $A$. Now, note that $u + (w-u) = w$ yields a contradiction. Thus, the sandwiching claim is proved by induction.

Even if $n$ is colored with $C$, this is followed by $A$ at position $1$ if we think about our numbers being in a circle. Thus, every $C$ corresponds to two $A$s. Now, if no two $C$'s share an $A$ in between them, then each $C$ would correspond to two unique $A$s. However, this would imply that the number of $C$s and $A$s are more than $\frac{n}{4}$ and $\frac{n}{2}$ respectively, which would be a contradiction since there are too few options left for $B$ (at most $\frac{n}{4}$).

Consider the minimal $x < n$ such that $x-1$ and $x+1$ are both colored with $C$. This means that $x-2$ and $x$ are colored with $A$. We can see that $x-u-1$ and $x-u+1$ cannot be colored with $A$ since $u$ is colored with $B$. By the minimality of $x$, not both of $x-u-1$ and $x-u+1$ can be colored with $C$. This forces one of them to be colored with $B$.

Assume $u > 2$, then $(u-2) + (x-u+1) = (x-1)$, where $u-2$ is colored with $A$ and $x-1$ is colored with $C$. This means $x-u+1$ must be colored with $C$, and hence, $x-u-1$ with $B$. However, $2$ is colored with $A$, and $2 + (x-u-1) = (x-u+1)$, yielding a contradiction. This forces $u = 2$.